# Get records from three tables to get ledger values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i am using below query to get records from two tables.

I want to fetch Debit amount from different table and result should get as below.

My current Query

```
select VM.voucher_no, VM.vch_date,VM.vch_remarks, case when DT.vch_amt_type2app_elm='Debit' then dt.amount else 0 end as Debitamt,
case when DT.vch_amt_type2app_elm='Credit' then dt.amount else 0 end as Creditamt 
from TBL_VOUCHER_DETAIL DT 
INNER JOIN TBL_Voucher_Master  VM 
ON VM.voucher_no = DT.voucherdetail2vmaster 
where VM.Vch_Date  between  '2015-06-17 15:12:51.000' and '2015-06-17 15:12:51.000'
and DT.voucherdetail2ledgers='L00012'
```

**and result as below**

```
Voucher No  Voucher Date    Remark  Debit   Credit
   49         17/06/2017      a       0     8229
```

Another table:- Tbl_invo   Fields name:- Inv no, date, cliName, Total, Dabit.

Comment: Sounds like you need to JOIN on the DEBIT table as well.

Comment: So why can't you do it?

Comment: Can you give another table name and fields pelase

Comment: Thanks @B House, I have added another table fields in question..

Comment: @RavirajJadhav Brill. whats common field between Tbl_invoice to tbl_vouhcer_master to join ?

Comment: @B Hose,Both having Invoice No. same field.

Comment: So join on InvoiceNo.

Answer (score 0):

@Raviraj if I understand correctly, you would like to replace dt.amount from the Debitamt and Creditamt columns with values from Tbl_invo. I'm not sure if you're using Tbl_invo.Total or Tbl_invo.Dabit but whichever one you choose you can either:
   Have another Inner Join to Tbl_invo (if it will always have a value) then replace dt.amount with Tbl_invo.Total (or whatever).
   Alternatively, you can replace dt.amount with a sub query to Tbl_invo for example:[image]

....

or with Inner Join:[image]

Comment: Thanks @Richard..  I want to replace only Debit amount which will come from Tbl_invo and credit amount will be same as it is.

Comment: Cool. I guess you can just update accordingly then i.e for the case of 'Credit' use dt.amount. Hope the above helped.